# Метод массива для подсчета числовых элементов массива

Tags: javascript

*Подскажите, метод массива для подсчета числовых элементов массива.*

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];  // В данном случае сумма равна 10
```

Comment: в массиве предполагается, что будут еще не числовые?

Answer (score 3):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - всё, что нужно, если в массиве будут только числа. Этот метод применяет функцию к аккумулятору и каждому значению массива (слева-направо), сводя его к одному значению.

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let result = myArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var total=0;
for(var i in arr) { total += arr[i]; }
```

*Нашел более простой вариант, может кому нибудь пригодится.*

Comment: А он более простой по сравнению с чем?